# ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Access denied (0x5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, caching

When I try to run the python command to connect the carla server to the client, I am getting "unable to move the cache error". Posting the full error code below:

```
[13908:1117/115305.393:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Zugriff verweigert (0x5)
[13908:1117/115305.394:ERROR:cache_util.cc(145)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\Cache_Data to C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\old_Cache_Data_000
[13908:1117/115305.394:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(196)] Unable to create cache
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening ?